# STM32f4-Discovery board FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos, stm32f4discovery

I'm new to RTOS and I'm trying to get freertos working with stm32f4 discovery board to get a better grip with embedded RTOS. I have searched all that I can to find a working version of freertos with the discovery board but I haven't found any that works.

I have tried all that I can to get it working but I'm probably missing something trivial which I can't seem to put my finger on. If anyone could provide me with a tutorial/project of a working blink example that would be amazing.

I have tried to make the example in the freertos website to work but I still haven't been able to, that is why I'm asking for help here.

All I need is a coocox project which I can open,build and flash it to the board and have an LED blinking. from there I can possibly find my away.

I have been at this for 2-3 weeks now so if anyone can provide the project I will be extremely. thankful. E-mail ID supriya213ss@gmail.com

best regards,
supriya

Comment: Looks more a question for http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough information about what you have done, or what is not working (you don't even say if it is compiling), to be able to give you more than an educated guess as a reply.

If you have followed the instructions to create a new project (http://www.freertos.org/Creating-a-new-FreeRTOS-project.html) then my educated guess would be that you have not installed the interrupt handlers (see "my application compiles but it does not run" http://www.freertos.org/FAQHelp.html)